# Create Zoomable image object on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on an image-related application for Windows Phone 8. After doing the required image processing, I currently display the output in "Image" Toolbox item, which seems to work well for me.
The coding here is done in C# + XAML.

Now I want to improve the UI and make the output image zoomable (using pinch to zoom). I would like to know how to create such a UI element which can be zoomed.

I understand that this might be a common requirement for many app developers. But I have been unable to find much reference for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the [windows phone toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) and use `GestureService.GestureListener`

Xaml:

```xml
...
xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
...

<Image Source="myImage.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <tk:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <tk:GestureListener PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" />
    </tk:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Image>
```

Code behind:

```cs
double initialScale = 0;

private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e) {
  initialScale = transform.ScaleX;
}

private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e) {
  transform.ScaleX = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
  transform.ScaleY = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
}
```